# Why javascript prototype is faster than closure? Should I use it for mobile performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have been researching about this and I seem to cannot find a straight answer to this question. A lot of people suggest that Prototype is faster than Closure. But I want to know more 'why' I have seen a bunch of [tests](http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-closures/71) and [blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/jj6fwa) even though the article is a bit old and I believe modern browsers would not make that much difference now.

Even [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs) is using prototype.

Do we know why typically prototype pattern is faster than Closure?

Comment: Prototype inheritance and closures are two difference things, so comparing the two doesn't make a lot of sense.  But it seems like you are talking in the context of constructor functions, specifically if you should add instance methods to the prototype or in the constructor function. Have a look at [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/218196). It all comes down to initializing a set of functions one time vs `n` times.

Comment: Faster for what exactly? Saying that something is faster with no particular use-case is pointless. Put together something that is principally ***correct***. If it doesn't perform, then start worrying about how to optimize it. Allowing optimization to drive design is fundamentally a broken concept.

Comment: For example, why the initialisation process for prototype is faster than Closure?